# Show that if $0 < \frac{1}{j},\frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{1}{N} \leq 1$, then $|\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{k}| \leq \frac{1}{N}$. ($j,k,N \in \mathbb{N}^+$))

Tags: analysis, absolute-value, cauchy-sequences

I am working through Tao's analysis I book and I am trying to prove that the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence (Proposition 5.1.11). I understand the proof, but I am having trouble showing why it is exactly that

$0 < \frac{1}{j},\frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{1}{N} \leq 1 \rightarrow |\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{k}| \leq \frac{1}{N}$.

I have tried manipulaing single inequalitis on their own and combining them in order to reach the final statement, but with no success. I am always left with an extra $\frac{1}{j},\frac{1}{k}$ on the side of the $\frac{1}{N}$ which doesn't allow me to conclude the reasoning. I suspect I am neglecting some simpler inequalities which would allow me to compare $|\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{k}|$ with $\frac{1}{N}$, but I don't see it yet. Any clue is more than welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $0 < \frac{1}{j} \leq \frac{1}{N}$ and $0 < \frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{1}{N}$.
Then we can subtract $\frac{1}{j}$ from the second inequality to get:
$$-\frac{1}{j} < \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{j} \leq \frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{j}$$ but we know $\frac{1}{j} > 0$ so $\frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{j} \leq \frac{1}{N}$ and we know $\frac{1}{j} \leq \frac{1}{N}$ so $-\frac{1}{N} \leq -\frac{1}{j}$ hence
$$-\frac{1}{N} \leq -\frac{1}{j} < \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{j} \leq \frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{j} \leq \frac{1}{N}$$
But we can simplify this to get:
$$-\frac{1}{N} \leq \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{j} \leq \frac{1}{N} \implies |\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{j}| \leq \frac{1}{N}$$

Comment: I knew there was something fairly trivial I was overlooking. In this case it was the fact that since $\frac{1}{j} > 0$, then $\frac{1}{N} > \frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{j}$. Thanks, for the insight.

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to mark as answered if it was useful!

Comment: Silly as it is, I don't know how to mark it as answered. How do I do that?

Comment: @DiegoCimadom After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can put this more simply: If $0\le x,y\le z$, then $|x-y|\le z$. And this is obvious, because the interval $[x,y]$ (or $[y,x]$ if $y<x$) is entirely contained in the interval $[0,z]$.

Comment: I can see the intuition behind your reasoning and I can understand it visually in my head, but I struggle to formalize it properly. In particular, how to you formalize the fact that the difference between $x$ and $y$ whatever that might be, must be smaller than $z$?

Comment: Formalisation can be over-rated. Any attempt to formalise this argument ends up just obscuring the intuition. But if that's what you want, see PhysicsKid's answer.

Comment: Formalisation might be over-rated, but I cannot, and do not want, to trust my intuition 100% alone. It wouldn't be the first time it tricks me.